# Hive dynamic partitioning not working

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to create dynamic partitions in a table.

1) First table is called stock1 where non-partitioned data is residing.
Here's the schema :

```
hive> describe stock1;
id                      int
xcg                     string
stock                   string
sector                  string
country                 string
dt                      string
open                    float
high                    float
low                     float
close                   float
volume                  int
adj_close               float
```

2) Second table is stock2 where I want the data to be partitioned dynamically.

```
hive> create table stock2(id int,stock string,sector string,country string,dt string,open float,high float,low float,close float,volume int,adj_close float) PARTITIONED BY (xchng string);
```

3) Now enabling dynamic partitioning:

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
```

4) loading the data into stock2 from stock1.

```
insert overwrite table stock2 partition(xchng)select id,stock,sector,country,dt,open,high,low,close,volume,adj_close,t.xcg as xchng from stock1 t;
```

Now when i check stock2 under the hive folder I only see a default partition

/user/hive/warehouse/stock.db/stock2/xchng=**HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION**

How to rectify so that I get seperate folders for each xchng.

Comment: You could try enabling dynamic partitioning before you create the second table

Comment: @cricket_007 : Thanks for quick reply but it didnt resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you check the all "xcg" values from "stock1". it is possible that at least some of the values or all of the values are not conforming String format. I mean for ex. there can be null or numbers instead of string.

Comment: Yes , I figured out that it was actually the reason, the data load didnt work and stock1 values were NULL.I reloaded the data and is now rectified.

Comment: in that case i request  you to mark my answer as the right answer and close it.